# iTextSharp open Document as 75%

Tags: java, itext

hi i am using iTextsharp to generate pdf ,i would like to open a pdf at 75%

Answer (score 1):

iTextSharp generates PDFs, it doesn't open them.

Also, if you're using Java you'd use iText (iTextSharp is the .NET version of iText, which is Java based).